# If facing issue of 'For IOS getting ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModule.requestPermission'

Tags: react-native, react-native-permissions

Then follow below step:
a. Most importantly, remember to add "reactNativePermissionsIOS": ["Camera"] and "postinstall": "react-native setup-ios-permissions && pod-install" to your package.json.
b. Run npm install.
c. Delete node_modules/react-native-qrcode-scanner/node_modules/react-native-permissions because it installs the deprecated 2.0.2. (You'll need to do this each time you clear your node_modules).